# Where does the phrase "reason in revolt" originate from?

Tags: socialism, marxism, propaganda

The phrase "*reason in revolt*" is commonly used in Marxist/Socialist literature, but I can't figure out where it came from. Who first said it or used it in writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you believe it, where seemingly everything in English does. Sheakspeare.

> Bi-fold authority! **where reason can revolt**
>   Without perdition, and loss assume all reason
>   Without revolt: this is, and is not, Cressid.
>
> William Shakespeare, "Troilus and Cressida", *[SCENE II. The same. Before Calchas' tent](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/troilus_cressida/troilus_cressida.5.2.html).*

---

In political (especially Marxist) context, the phrase comes from the (literally incorrect :) British Translation of the song "[The Internationale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Internationale)" - please read the Wikipedia article linked if you aren't aware of why that song is important in Marxist context.

> [For reason in revolt now thunders](https://www.marxists.org/history/ussr/sounds/lyrics/international.htm)
>   And at last ends the age of cant.

(Actually, original French lyrics phrase was "La raison tonne en son cratère", translated by Google as "Reason thunders in its crater")

Please note that the [Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reason%20in%20revolt&year_start=1860&year_end=1880&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creason%20in%20revolt%3B%2Cc0) does not show that exact phrase used before 1866

Comment: Ooh, this seems promising, if a slight deviation. I'll wait for a few more comments before ticking :)

Comment: @J.B. - expanded.

Comment: Many thanks, especially for the multiple sources :)